# Should I Place My Video Surveillance System in a DMZ?

Tags: port-forwarding, home-surveillance

So I just purchased a video surveillance system for the house and am concerned (perhaps unecessarily) about forwarding port 80.  So, my question is two fold:

Should I be concerned about port forwarding just to the Surveillance DVR, and if I should be concerned about that, then is placing it in the DMZ a better way to go?

It may be that I don't have to worry about forwarding port 80 if it is only on that device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not place your surveillance system on DMZ, I would also STRONGLY recommend that you use a different port (because your cam could be searchable on Google), you can set up forwarding in router's config page.

Comment: Interesting.  I would have been under the impression that since it asks for a password before presenting the camera views, that Google could not search it.  Or are you saying that the IP address itself would be picked up as a "web cam" site?